# assignment in javascript and the var keyword

Tags: javascript, node.js, browser

I was reading the 'learning Node' book and I was stuck in a very simple issue, one that I haven't given too much thought about: assignment in javascript.

The author states that we should realize that by using the Node's REPL, the following would return undefined:

```
var a = 2
(undefined)
```

while the code below will return '2' in the REPL:

```
a = 2
2
```

why is that? the code right above is not an attribution? how come? If the var 'a' hasn't existed until that point in the code, how come it is not and attribution?

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6297332/why-do-variable-declarations-in-the-console-keep-returning-undefined .

Comment: Why is there a 'browser' tag on this question?

Comment: the JS REPL in firefox (firebug), chrome and IE > 8 give the same results

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Per [ECMA-262 § 12.2](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-12.2), a *VariableStatement* (that is, `var identifier=value`) explicitly returns nothing.  Additionally, a *VariableStatement* is a Statement; Statements do not return values, and it is invalid to put a Statement somewhere an Expression would go.

For example, none of the following make sense because they put a Statement where you need value-yielding Expressions:

```
var a = var b;
function fn() { return var x; }
```

Per [§ 11.13.1](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.13.1), **assignment** to a variable (`identifier=value`) returns the assigned value.

---

When you write `var a = 1;`, it declares `a` and initalizes its value to `1`.  Because this is a *VariableStatement*, it returns nothing, and the REPL prints `undefined`.

`a=1` is an expression that assigns `1` to `a`.  Since there is no `a`, JavaScript implicitly creates a *global* `a` in normal code (but would throw a `ReferenceError` in strict mode, since you're not allowed to implicitly create new globals in strict mode).

Regardless of whether or not `a` existed before, the expression still returns the assigned value, `1`, so the REPL prints that.

Comment: *Further reading*: You may also be interested in [the difference between function statements/declarations and function expressions](http://kangax.github.com/nfe/).

Answer (score 1):

Just guessing here - this could probably be verified by referring to the ECMAScript 5th Edition spec (but man that thing is a pain) - it probably has to do with the specification of the "var" statement vs assigning attributes to the "global" object.

When you declare a variable and assign a value to it (`var a=2`) the returned value is likely "undefined" because that's what the spec says the "var" statement should return.

When you assign a variable to a symbol without using the "var" statement you are actually assigning a value to an attribute of the global object of that name.  That is, `a=2` is the same as saying `window.a=2` and we know that assinging a value to an attribute returns the value assigned.

Comment: ...but `var a=2` is also equivalent to `window.a=2` in a REPL context (if your REPL is browser based, because the window object is the global object itself).

Comment: You're on the right track, but this is incorrect.  It has nothing to do with the global object.  `var a; ... a = 1;` assigns to a local variable, but the `a=1` would still return `1`.  A `var` statement always returns nothing; an assignment expression (whether to a local, already defined variable, or to a implicit global) always returns the assigned value.

Answer (score 1):

`var a = 2` is a statement. Thus it has no value.

Comment: var _does_ return no value, but not because it's a statement. Other statements do return values.  E.g. `for(i = 0; i < 1; i++) {'hello'};`

Answer (score 1):

You are evaluating a statement list. When evaluating a statement list, the value of the last value-producing statement is returned. http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-12.1 - note the examples at the end of this section. If no statements in the list returned a value, then nothing will be returned (this is `undefined` in JavaScript).

The variable statement, does not return a value. http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-12.2

The assignment operator, does return a value (as well as performing the assignment). http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.13.1