# mongoose console returns undefined

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

i've installed mongoose using 
`projectFolder$ npm install mongoose'

i have no issue with mongo console but when i entered the following commands

`projectFolder$ node`

`>`

`>var mongoose = require('mongoose');`

`undefined`

i have no issue starting node server, and mongo server as i could start up my website no issue. I ran into trouble just when i try the above commands in the console. i confirmed that mongoose is installed and the cursor returned undefined.

Comment: `undefined` is always the result of a `var` statement.  See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13180195/assigment-in-javascript-and-the-var-keyword).

Comment: @JohnnyHK if `undefined` is the result, does that mean the `var mongoose = require('mongoose`)` was successfully executed?

Comment: Yes, you would get a `Cannot find module 'mongoose'` exception if the `require` failed.  Just type `mongoose` at the node prompt to see what it got set to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checks for node_modules/mongoose folder in your project
If not, try it again:

```
npm install mongoose
```

EDIT:
I removed `var` and works it

Comment: yes `projectFolder/node_modules/mongoose` exists and i already tried `npm install mongoose`