# Why does browser returns undefined?

Tags: javascript

I have found a phenomenon that confused me when I run simple javascript code from the browser console(Chrome & Firefox).

When I typed say

```
>var a = "a"
```

The browser will return a string

```
>"undefined"
```

but if I just typed

```
>a = "a"
```

The browser will return the string

```
>"a"
```

Why is this case?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/8EF5w/ This returns "a", not "undefined". Can you reproduce what you're getting?

Comment: @Houseman That is not what OP mean. As the question says, this occur when you run the line straight from the console, not when you log it to the console.

Comment: It's not the _String_ `"undefined"` but the actual thing `undefined`, because `var` gives no return value.

Comment: See explanation http://stackoverflow.com/a/13180929/853295

Comment: The result of an assignment expression in JS is the assigned value. The `var a = "a"` case is a statement, and has no such result value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you write

```
alert(var a = 'a')
```

You get a syntax error, `var` is part of the javascript syntax, it doesn't return anything.

The `a = 'a'` portion, however, does return something.

You can do `var a = b = c = d = 'e';`

And the `d = 'e'` returns `e`, which gets fed into the `c=d` which is really `c = 'e'`, etc.  Once you get to the var it stops returning the value.

If you type `var a;` you get undefined.  `var a = 'b'` is essentially just shorthand for `var a;  a = b;`

Comment: @DaveThx Dave for the clarification

Answer (score 3):

The console is showing the result of the evaluated expression.  Declaring the variable and assigning it at the same time with

```
var a = 'a'
```

does not return anything, so you get **undefined**.  The result of just the assignment part

```
b = 'b'
```

returns the value, so you see it in the console.

```
var a = b = c = d = 'foo';
```

That returns **undefined**, although several variables have been set.  The real purpose of the expression was to define the scope of the variables, setting the value was just a bit of shorthand.