# Different output of same snippet on different environments?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have this snippet of code

```
function foo() {
    console.log(this.bar);
}

var bar = "bar1";
var o2 = { bar: "bar2", foo: foo };
var o3 = { bar: "bar3", foo: foo };

foo();          // "bar1"
o2.foo();       // "bar2"
o3.foo();       // "bar3"
```

when run in browser it shows the output

```
bar1
bar2
bar3
```

but when run it with node it outputs

```
undefined
bar2
bar3
```

Can someone explain why am I getting different outputs?

Comment: Tried your example, the output is the same. Which node version do you use?

Comment: does this explain what you see? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13180195/assignment-in-javascript-and-the-var-keyword

Comment: @EugeneOlisevich I think OP is running it as a node script, not in the REPL

Comment: I test ran as OP described, in a browser and  on nodejs. The OP's results seem valid.

Comment: @EugeneOlisevich I am using node v7.5.0